# How to rollback network configuration changes done over SSH in case of failure?

Tags: networking, ssh, command-line, remote

I'm about to change `iptables` configuration and interface speed and duplex settings over SSH. What are the possibilities to rollback the changes in case of host becomes unreachable? I guess simple:

```
ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 dev eth0; ping -c1 8.8.8.8 || ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev eth0
```

..is bit risky because if SSH connection drops immediately after the IP address change, then shell should be also killed and `ping -c1 8.8.8.8 || ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev eth0` part is never executed? Should one use `crontab` in case of dangerous changes on a remote host? Any other clever method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a `screen` or `tmux` session, set up a shell that will reverse your changes after a delay. I don't know anything about `iptables`, so can't help with that, but something like this has saved my proverbial bacon on numerous occasions while altering live firewall configs on FreeBSD:

```
# In one `screen` or `tmux` window
% sleep 60 && <command to reverse changes>
```

In another window, you can now make your changes, and if they work you can kill the `sleep`. Note that because we're using `&&`, the command to back out your changes won't be run when you kill `sleep`.

If your changes don't work, wait a few seconds and your back out command will run.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is in my opinion more convenient than the `crontab` one.

Comment: actually it is always a good idea to use `screen` or `tmux` when working through ssh, because if for some reason the connection drops your running applications won't get a `SIGPIPE` and die, and you can always reattach later

Comment: @pqnet Absolutely. I have been encouraging my colleagues to do just this, and we have a lot fewer "my long running job died" complaints. We do have a lot of forgotten `screen` sessions on most of our servers, though...

Comment: Instead, after running the command, you can just `Ctrl`+`z`, `disown -h`, `bg`. If the connection dies, the command will still be running.

Comment: @Sparhawk No, if you do that the command will block or crash trying to print to the dead terminal. (Nitpickers: yes, yes, it might work, in the same way that falling from the fifth floor isn't guaranteed to kill you.)

Comment: @Gilles I'm not entirely sure of the inner workings and implications, but I thought this was the "recommended" way to exit while keeping processes running? I've used it before successfully, at least.

Comment: @Sparhawk You need to redirect the output (stdout and stderr) to a file (or `/dev/null`, but here you do want to save the output). Screen/tmux is easier to get right.