# Automatic rollback of broken configuration changes?

Tags: debian, configuration, backup, system-recovery

I run a headless home server and sometimes need to make configuration changes that have the potential to break remote access. Is there a tool or system service that can be set to define what constitutes a "good" state (e.g. can ping 1.1.1.1 and some remote host can see me) and have it roll back changes automatically if it detects a "bad" state? I saw [one answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149867/how-to-rollback-network-configuration-changes-done-over-ssh-in-case-of-failure) that provides a very targeted suggestion, but I'm looking for something more general that I can leave running all the time.

In a perfect world, it would look like it literally rolled back time. But I don't want to run a VM, so I'll settle for detecting and automatically restoring files I manually edit under `/etc`. It would even be valuable to have a service automatically roll back all changes to `/etc` and reboot the system unless I specifically indicate the new state is good within five minutes of the change being made.

Is there any package or service that does this?

Answer (score 0):

[Timeshift](https://wiki.debian.org/timeshift) can be used to achieve your goal. In a headless Debian server,
Timeshift provide a CLI tool.

Install:

```
sudo apt install timeshift
```

Basic cli options from manpages:

```
List:
  --list[-snapshots]         List snapshots

Backup:
   --create                   Create snapshot (even if not scheduled)

Restore:
  --restore                  Restore snapshot
  --clone                    Clone current system

Delete:
  --delete                   Delete snapshot

Examples:
timeshift --create --comments "after update" --tags D
timeshift --restore --snapshot '2014-10-12_16-29-08' --target /dev/sda1
timeshift --delete  --snapshot '2014-10-12_16-29-08'
```

Answer (score 0):

You describe various concepts:

## Revision control

This is a tool that lets you role back source-code or configurations.

## Automatic deployment

Have configurations that are added to revision control automatically deployed.

## Automated test

Code or configurations are tested before or after deployment.
If done before, then a pass can trigger deployment.
If done after, then a fail can trigger rollback.